# How to create a Service Command for Paste in mac Application that doesn't normally allow it?

Tags: javascript, macos

So for my work, we have a Javascript program for transcribing audio, line by line, with timings marked accordingly. Because most of what we transcribe is already readily found online, it would make sense to copy and paste. But because it is too good of an idea, the makers of the Javascript app (Mac os) decided to leave that one out. And more than that, conventional commands (Command + V) don't work. (Copying works just fine).

What I want to be able to do is to copy from a browser (Chrome) and into the mac os application with a single service command.

I have tried creating a service command myself in the Automator tool but my knowledge of coding/etc is awful. I managed to get it a form of it to work, but the spacing between the lines is all janky.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbEKg.png)

Comment: Please provide the solution your tried. You can not expect us to write a fully functional solution for you without any further contribution of yours.

Comment: - what do you mean by 'Javascript program'? is it browser-based? if not, please specify the engine/framework.
- 'copy from a Windows browser into mac os' - are you copying from one operating system to another?... chrome is not an exclusive windows browser, if you just mean 'copy from chrome to an app' pls remove 'Windows', it's confusing.
- add relevant version numbers if you can.

Comment: @giladmayani Sorry everyone, I am new to most all of these terms. All I want to do is create a service in the Automator that allows for the pasting of materials from the Clipboard into the app.